# created virtual environment , but cant access it

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtual

---

it shows created virtual environment. But it is not redirect to virtual environment . after I upgraded the pip no changes where appear . please help me to get that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej9dU.jpg)

Comment: Upload the error message. Use StackOverflow image upload tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must navigate to where your virtual environment is installed, then execute the activation script.

**cmd.exe**
`C:\> <venv>\Scripts\activate.bat`

**PowerShell**
`PS C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenv is created. You need to activate virtual environment too

Like:

```
venv_name\Scripts\activate
```